# Karabiner-Elements: How to re-map caps_lock based on applications

Tags: keyboard, macos, keybindings

## Objective

This is more about to confirm if this configuration is correct to do remapping with Karabiner-Elements to remap:

- caps_lock to left_control if it is in Terminal
- caps_lock to left_control if it is in Emacs
- caps_lock to left_command otherwise

Appreciate if someone can confirm if this is good enough, or suggest better/correct ways.

### Background

Looking for a way to remap keys in Mac Sierra and found Karabiner-Elements for the purpose, but not many examples and documentations about the syntax of karabiner.json. Hence looking for inputs.

### Code

```
"complex_modifications": {
    "parameters": {
        "basic.to_if_alone_timeout_milliseconds": 1000
    },
    "rules": [
        {
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "description": "Change caps_lock to left_command in Terminal.",
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "bundle_identifiers": [
                                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$"
                            ],
                            "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                        }
                    ],
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "caps_lock",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "left_control"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "basic"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "caps_lock to left_control in Emacs",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "bundle_identifiers": [
                                "org\\.gnu\\.Emacs"
                            ],
                            "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                        }
                    ],
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "caps_lock",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "left_control"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "basic"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "caps_lock to left_command otherwise",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "caps_lock",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "left_command"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "basic"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Appreciate if someone can confirm if this is good enough, or suggest
> better/correct ways.

Using [goku](https://github.com/yqrashawn/GokuRakuJoudo), for remapping <kbd>Caps Lock ⇪</kbd> to <kbd>Left ⌃</kbd> if it is in **Terminal**, **Emacs** and to <kbd>Left ⌘</kbd> otherwise, use these three strings:

```clj
[:caps_lock :left_control :emacs]
[:caps_lock :left_control :terminal]
[:caps_lock :left_command]
```

Assuming you predefined `:emacs` & `:terminal` in the `:applications {}` section above:

```clj
:applications {
    :emacs ["org.gnu.Emacs"]
    :terminal ["com.apple.Terminal"]
}
```

---

If you’re using Karabiner only, the settings will be:

```json
{
    "description" : "Caps Lock",
    "manipulators" : [ {
        "from" : {
            "key_code" : "caps_lock"
        },
        "to" : [ {
            "key_code" : "left_control"
        } ],
        "conditions" : [ {
            "type" : "frontmost_application_if",
            "bundle_identifiers" : ["org.gnu.Emacs"]
        } ],
        "type" : "basic"
    }, {
        "from" : {
            "key_code" : "caps_lock"
        },
        "to" : [ {
            "key_code" : "left_control"
        } ],
        "conditions" : [ {
            "type" : "frontmost_application_if",
            "bundle_identifiers" : ["com.apple.Terminal"]
        } ],
        "type" : "basic"
    }, {
        "from" : {
            "key_code" : "caps_lock"
        },
        "to" : [ {
            "key_code" : "left_command"
        } ],
        "type" : "basic"
    } ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Share my configuration:

```
{
  "title": "Function key if",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Function key if",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "delete_forward"
          },
          "to": [
            {
            "key_code": "p",
            "modifiers": "left_command"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [{
            "type": "frontmost_application_if",
            "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.microsoft\\.VSCode$"] }],
          "type": "basic"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "delete_forward"
          },
          "to": [
            {
            "key_code": "i",
            "modifiers": ["left_command","left_option"]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [{
            "type": "frontmost_application_if",
            "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.google\\.Chrome$"] }],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).